# Why do active methylene compounds give Sn2 reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

[image]

I dont understand why they are strong nucleophiles when the negative charge is resonance stabilised. Also it is bulky, is there any chance of elimination?

Comment: You may find useful these links for text formatting ( not to be applied to titles ):
 [notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [text + formula formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: What exactly is a *"strong"* nucleophile? IMHO, for the purposes of organic chemistry, it suffices to know that it is *a* nucleophile. Nucleophilicity scales do exist, but aren't really needed if you just want to draw a curly arrow mechanism. Also, if the charge weren't resonance stabilised, then lots of bad things happen. [Alkyllithiums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organolithium_reagent) will react in all sorts of conceivable ways (as a base, as a nucleophile, lithium–halogen exchange). Tempering the negative charge helps to keep the reactivity under control.

Comment: I'm in high school and I've been taught while comparing nucleophilic strengths(I'm really sorry) , nucleophiles with delocalized charges are poorer nucleophiles because they cannot donate electrons as effectively as the ones with localized charges. I haven't really dealt with Sn1,Sn2 questions involving resonance stabilized nucleophiles before this.(Pardon me for any mistakes, English is not my first language)

Comment: Hi Jen, welcome to ChemSE. Your question is quite insightful for a high school student. Whether or not the nucleophile/base is resonance stabilized is not the main issue. What counts is the relative rate of the irreversible SN2 vs. E2 reactions. I did a quick Chemical Abstracts search of this reaction and found yields of 16%, 21% and 40% for the SN2 product. These yields are modest at best. They may indicate substantial E2 elimination is competing with displacement. I will dismiss poor technique in isolating the product. ;)